# confirm only 1 time function with jquery

Tags: jquery, function, confirm

i have this function that will shuffle a list of images, when i press on a #shuffle button i want to trigger a message, if is confirmed the second time i will not want to ask again!

how to code this?

```
$('#shuffle').click(function(){
  if(confirm('This will shuffle all your bla bla bla')){
    $("#upimagesQueue li").shuffle();       
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a variable, like this:

```
var confirmed = false;
$('#shuffle').click(function(){
  if(confirmed || confirm('This will shuffle all your bla bla bla')){
    $("#upimagesQueue li").shuffle();  
    confirmed = true;     
  }
});
```

This starts with the confirm not being acknowledged, but the first time it is, it's set to true.  This means the first part of the `condition1 OR condition2` in your `if()` would be true, so the confirm wouldn't pop up again.

Alternatively, you can use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the variable for this:

```
$('#shuffle').click(function(){
  if($(this).data('confirmed') || confirm('This will shuffle all your bla bla bla')){
    $(this).data('confirmed', true);   
    $("#upimagesQueue li").shuffle();   
  }
});
```

Comment: This will work, but it seems a little silly to have extra variables when you can just unbind the event.

Comment: @SeanJA - Show me a cleaner/shorter way (with *all* the functionality, like I have above) that does this and I'll concede it's a better option :)

Comment: For the first one, I hate it when the global namespace is full of oneoff variables (maybe that is just me). The data one is quite clever in avoiding that pet peeve of mine.

Comment: @SeanJA - Same pet peeve of mine as well, my favorite use is for timeout storage for delayed searches on typing like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584329/javascript-settimeout-help-needed/2584439#2584439

Answer (score 0):

This is a better more readable way

```
$('#shuffle').bind('click', function(event){
    if(confirm('are you sure?')){
        $(this).unbind(event);
        $('#shuffle').bind('click', function(){
            $("#upimagesQueue li").shuffle();
        });
        $("#upimagesQueue li").shuffle();
    }
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Could also be written as:

```
$('#shuffle').bind('click', function(event){
    if(confirm('are you sure?')){
        $(this).unbind(event).click(function(){
            $("#upimagesQueue li").shuffle();
        })
        $("#upimagesQueue li").shuffle();
    }
});
```

Comment: It also needs to run when you click confirm the first time, once you add that in (twice now), I doubt this is "more readable."  If however, you bound an event handler that did the confirm (or cancel) first then the shuffling as a separate bind and unbound the first interrupting handler, it might be cleaner...but then you need a named handler so still longer.

Comment: Since it is already being selected, and jQuery returns `this` and .shuffle() is a function, you can chain it

Comment: @SeanJA - That would only hold true if `#shuffle` was what was being shuffled :)  Check the question again, it's actually shuffling `"#upimagesQueue li"`

Comment: @Nick You got me there, I didn't realise that at first... you win this round sir

Comment: @Nick I would rewrite the shuffle function to take a selector... but I think that might be out of scope

Comment: @SeanJA - Good show :) Don't get me wrong though - I'm all for being shown a new better, shorter, or easier way I never thought of before...it's one of the best ways to learn/grow in my opinion :)